# Use after free error?

Tags: c

```
int main(void) {
  int* p = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
  int* q = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
  *p = 10;
  *q = 20;
  p = q;
  printf(“%d %d”, *p, *q);
  free(p); 
  free(q);
}
```

Why does the above code contain use-after-free error? There's no more expression after free(p) and free(q). Obviously we are not using them anymore!

Comment: Perhaps the line `p = q;` should be `*p = *q;`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have two problems here.

First, you are deleting the same heap variable twice:

```
  free(p); 
  free(q);
```

Second, you have a memory-leak, because the variable created by `p` is no longer accessible.

---

Notice that onebyone's comment is really important. If you change the line:

```
p = q;
```

into:

```
*p = *q;
```

There would be no problems at all in your code :) Hello Pointers!

Answer (score 4):

You set `p` to `q`, so you are `free()`ing it twice.

Answer (score 2):

Since `q` and `p` point to the same memory at the point you are `free`ing them, you're effectively `free`ing the memory twice.

Answer (score 2):

Because here:

```
p = q;
```

...you're throwing away the old value of `p`.  You now have *two* copies of the pointer that was returned by the second `malloc`, and *none* of the pointer that was returned by the first `malloc`.

So then here:

```
free(p); 
free(q);
```

...the same pointer value gets passed to `free` twice: use-after-free error.  The *other* pointer value never gets passed to `free` at all: memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fundamental memory manipulation error!

Never do so!

You allocate memory at pointer p and after that you just rewrite pointer at `p=q`.

Previous value of pointer you lost, **p** is a lost pointer!

You can never free the memory allocated above for pointer **p**! It's a lost memory block for **p**.

It's memory leak... Try to free it at line `free(p)` in real free memory allocated for pointer **q**, but  not for **p**!.

Next line `free(q)` is another try to free the same memory that was freed in previous line. That will be unpredictable behavior depending on the system it may be nothing special, and may be an error at program finish.

You must replace line `free(p)` before line `p=q`.

**And always before rewrite pointer with previously allocated memory free them! Consider it a strict rule!**

Answer (score -1):

The pointer 'p' is assigned the address of 'q'. Therefore, when 'free(p)' and 'free(q)' are called, it tries to free the same memory location twice and CWE-401: Memory Leak. The original address of 'p' is lost when 'p = q' is executed, causing a memory leak. Here is the fixed code

```cpp
int main(void) {
  int* p = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
  int* q = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
  *p = 10;
  *q = 20;
  free(p); // Free the memory allocated to p before reassigning
  p = q;
  printf(“%d %d”, *p, *q);
  free(p); 
  p = NULL; // Set p to NULL after freeing
  if (p != q) {
    free(q); // Only free q if it is not pointing to the same location as p
  }
  q = NULL; // Set q to NULL after freeing
}
```

Comment: after p=NULL; the check  (p!=q) will always be true and also result in a double freeing of p/q;