# Linked List not properly being deleted when passed as a parameter in C++

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I have a method called deleteList that takes a head of a single linked list as an input and it removes all the nodes.

In the method deleteList I can verify that all the nodes are deleted, but when the execution returns back to the main, myList is not empty. So in the subsequent call to LengthOfList, the code fails with an exception.

*[Please note that I am unable to change the signature of deleteList]*

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct CodeNode* List;

struct CodeNode
{
    char data;
    List next;

    CodeNode(char new_data, List new_next)
        : data(new_data), next(new_next) {
    }

};

int LengthOfList(List head)
{
    int len = 0;
    for (List ptr = head; ptr != nullptr; ptr = ptr->next) {
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}

void deleteList(List head)
{
    List prev = head;

    while (head)
    {
        head = head->next;
        delete(prev);
        prev = head;
    }
    // I can verify that head is null and all the nodes have been deleted
}

int main(void)
{
    List temp1 = new CodeNode('3', nullptr);
    List temp2 = new CodeNode('2', temp1);
    List myList = new CodeNode('1', temp2);

    cout << "Before " << LengthOfList(myList);
    deleteList(myList);
    cout << "After " << LengthOfList(myList); // CODE FAILS HERE because myList is pointing to a bad memory address (it SHOULD be NULL)
}
```

Comment: Assigning to a function's (non-reference) argument has no effect outside that function. There is nothing special about pointers. (Also, aliasing pointer types is one of those things that seem like a great idea until it's a terrible idea and you never do it again.)

Comment: `but when the execution returns back to the main, myList is not empty.` Its free'd memory. Using it is undefined behavior.

Comment: `I can verify that head is null and all the nodes have been deleted`. - You can verify this because the `head` pointer is at the end of linked list.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use the struct keyword together with an identifier as in `typedef struct CodeNode* List;` and instead you should simply use `typedef CodeNode* List;` and besides that, use a using declaration instead of `typedef` like `using List = CodeNode*;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Pass by reference*

```
void deleteList(List& head)
```

The `&` makes all the difference. If you want a function to alter a variable in the calling function then you pass by reference.

All your code is doing is modifying the variable `head` in the function `deleteList` which is **not** the same variable as `head` in `main`. By using a reference you make `head` in `deleteList` an *alias* for the variable used in the calling function, and therefore changes to it effect that variable.

Another option is to *return* the changed variable, so in `main`

```
myList = deleteList(myList);
```

and in `deleteList`

```
List deleteList(List head)
{
    ...
    return head; // return modified head
}
```

Both approaches work, it's a style choice which you choose.

I just noticed your comment, 'please note I'm unable to change the signature of `deleteList`'. Then I'm afraid your code is guaranteed to fail. There is no solution given the peculiar constraints you have been given.

It's amazing how often we see this here, newbie struggling with some problem, but unable to use any of the solutions that any normal programmer would use because of artificial constraints placed on the task by their teacher. In some cases, like yours, these constraints are so severe that there is literally no solution to the task that they've been given. I suggest you ask your teacher for some advice.

Comment: To add to this, it’s important because a pointer to free’d memory isn’t automatically nullptr. And reading it (comparing it to nullptr) will lead to [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

Answer (score 2):

In short, your solution is doing exactly this.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

typedef struct CodeNode* List;
struct CodeNode {
    char data;
    List next;
    CodeNode(char new_data, List new_next): data(new_data), next(new_next) {}
};

int main() {
    List myList = new CodeNode('1', nullptr);
    cout<<myList->data<<endl;
    delete(myList);
    cout<<myList->data<<endl;
    return 0;
}

// given error
// AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 
// 0x602000000010 at pc 0x000000342fd6 bp 0x7fffcb6b5110 sp 0x7fffcb6b5108
```

And, accessing `myList` after deletion is supposed to be `undefined` as this is an example of `heap use after free` which occurs when a program continues to `use a pointer after it has been freed`.

**Useful Links**

- [ASAN heap use after free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53558983/asan-heap-use-after-free)
- [Use after free error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677850/use-after-free-error)

**Solution**

john's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75480990/7769239) has already given the answer on how `passing by reference` can actually update the underlying variable and produce the desired effect.

I just wanted to supplement the reason for your understanding.

Comment: "it is supposed to fail" actually no, its just undefined

Comment: Well, something like, it is supposed to fail to output a value as it is undefined.

Comment: no. Its not supposed to fail to output a value. It can do anything. It could output the value that was previously stored in `data`, nothing wrong with that

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible for the `AddressSanitizer` tool to detect that issue before outputting previously-stored data` or doing anything arbitrarily? In a language like rust, these scenario is prohibited even in compile time as I am aware. Pardon my understanding, I am aware that a `delete` or `free` operation can indeed keep the value intact as per its implementation. But, in what scenario would the detection of an AddressSanitizer tool for such scenarios would be disabled or turned off?

Comment: " But, in what scenario would the output or detection of an AddressSanitizer tool be disabled or turned off?" there is no AddressSanitizer by default. Its a tool used for debugging only. Once you make a release build there is no AddressSanitizer